# Failed: invalid element state error getting when i am trying to upload image in protractor

Tags: protractor, image-uploading

I am using the following code to upload:

```
var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = 'Desktop:/mdkg.jpg';
var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
var button = element(by.css('[ngf-select]'));
button.click();
var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
input.sendKeys(absolutePath);
element(by.buttonText('Post Image')).click();
```

I have multiple steps to upload images:

1. when I click on icon modal should open. modal contains two buttons they are upload image and post image.
2. when I click on upload image it should navigate to the local computer (respective folder).
3. for ex: pictures, I can pick one image , and that image should comes to modal,now modal contains image.
4. now click on post image button it should post.

HTML code :

> ```
>     <div ngf-drop ng-model="files" ngf-pattern="image/*" data-ngf-multiple="true" ng-repeat="image in images1" ngf-size>
>         <img  src="{{image}}" width = "100%" height = "100%" class="m-l img-responsive img-rounded m-b" alt="post images">
>         </img-crop>
>         <span ng-show="loading" class="text-center col-xs-12" ></span>
>     </div>
> </div>
> <div class="modal-actions ">
>     <button type="submit " class="btn-link modal-action ">
>         <strong><span class="icon icon-user "></span>postImg</strong>
>     </button>
>     <button type="button" id="fileinput"   ng-model="files" ngf-select accept="image/* " data-ngf-multiple="true" class="btn-link
> ```
>
> modal-action ">
>               **upload image**

Comment: Can you show the HTML representation of the relevant part of the page containing all the elements used inside the test? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe <button type="submit " class="btn-link modal-action ">
            <strong>Post Image</strong>
        </button><button type="button" id="fileinput"   ng-model="files" ngf-select accept="image/* " data-ngf-multiple="true" class="btn-link modal-action ">
            <strong>upload Image</strong></button>.this is my html to upload image

Comment: Please add new code in the question, not in the comments.